# Creating a autosave directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, restangular

I want to create a directive as an attribute where i want to attach an autosave capability to other directives. I thought about creating a directive which puts a watch on an attribute (model) passed in. The debounce function is from lodash and prevents an execution on each keystroke. The put method is from the restangular model.

My idea so far

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).directive('autosave',[ function () {
    'use strict';

    function autosaveController($scope) {

        function saveModel(newModel, oldModel) {
            if(newModel !== oldModel && newModel.put) {
                $scope.model.put();
            }
        }

        $scope.$watch($scope.model, _.debounce(saveModel, 5000), true);
    }

return {

    restrict : 'A',

    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        return autosaveController($scope);
    }],

    scope : {
        model : '='
    }

};

}]);
```

But i did not get this to work, then i thought may i better put this in my restangular model, but i havent got scope there. How do i add this autosave feature properly? I need to be able to define which object in the scope will be watched and attach a watch to it so i get updates on changes.

Edit: Created a plunker showing the idea:

http://plnkr.co/edit/I8GK8zHV8fOXY0zMa1AL?p=preview

I tried to set a scope on both directives and got an error that this is not allowed. (something like two isolated scopes not allowed)

Can i create an isolated scope on a attribute directive at all?

Basically i need to pass in the model to the autosave directive

Comment: 1. Can you create a plunkr that shows this not working? Edit: 2. Is the first parameter to the $watch function meant to either be a string, where the expression is $eval-uated, or a function?

Comment: created a plunker, maybe its only a little thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move the `autosave` directive inside the `car` directive so that the scope of `autosave` is a child of the scope of `car`, not the other way around.

Also for passing parameters to `autosave` you'll need to use attributes (`$attrs`), not `$scope`.

So `<div class="car" autosave model="car">`

and

```
app.directive('autosave',[ function () {
    'use strict';

    function autosaveController($scope, $emelent, $attrs) {

        function saveModel(newModel, oldModel) {
           //...
        }

        $scope.$watch($attrs.model, _.debounce(saveModel, 5000), true);
    }

return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link: autosaveController
}
```

[Here is the modified plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/bOUpAdt6GxA6oDZH8OzR?p=preview)

Comment: works perfect, additionally i check if an id exists on the old model because otherwise it will trigger when the model gets loaded